# what is the difference "might be able to" and "might have to"?

Tags: modal-verbs

What is the difference "might be able to" and "might have to"?

1. Tell me about your problem. I **might be able** to help you.
2. I'm not free this evening, but I **might be able** to meet you tomorrow.
3. I don't know if I'll be free on Sunday. I **might have to** work.
4. I can come to the meeting, but I **might have to** leave before the end.

Please, explain to me.

Comment: Besides "able to" indicating an ability and "have to" indicating a requirement? What did your own research into the definitions of these words show? Put this in your question, please.

Comment: No, I meant that you should add what research you've done, and what questions you still have after doing that research. See https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is no overlap at all between the meanings of _be able to_ and _have to_. What they do have in common is that each is close in meaning to a (different) modal: _be able to_ to _can_, and _have to_ to _must_.

Comment: ***to be able to*** and ***to have to*** mean completely different things, as can easily be established using a dictionary. Preceding ether by ***might*** doesn't affect this.

Answer (score 0):

We using **might be able to** if we have power to do this thing.

We using **might have to** if we predict what we probably need to do this thing.

Comment: "Might be able to" does not imply certainty of ability, or that we **can**, but that there is a possibility.

Comment: Also, "We using" is not grammatical